# Change offset / margin position based on page scroll location

Tags: html, css-position, margin, offset, fixed

I have three div elements on my webpage. One on the top ( for the menu ), one on the left ( for user information ), and the last on the right ( for user posts ). I have the user information section in a fixed position, which works good, but also when I scroll down the page, it shows the gap at the top of the page where the menu once was. Is there a way to have the top offset / margin change when the menu isn't on the screen? I want to do this without javascript if possible. Every search i did showed only javascript, but I want pure css / html for this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use javascript the answer is "No."

There is no way to check the scroll position and change the CSS only with CSS.